# Como persistir objetos em uma tabela se ainda não tenho a chave estrangeira?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Tenho uma classe de Equipamentos que possui uma lista de AgendaFuncionamento. Elas estão mapeadas assim:

```html
@Entity
@Table(schema = "pesquisa", name = "sre_equipamento")
public class Equipamento implements Serializable {

...

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "equipamento")
private List<AgendaFuncionamento> listaAgendaFuncionamento = new ArrayList<>();

...

}
```

```html
@Entity
@Table(schema = "pesquisa", name = "sre_agenda_funcionamento")
public class AgendaFuncionamento implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "dia_semana")
    private int diaSemana;

    @Column(name = "hora_inicio")
    //@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    private LocalTime horarioInicial;

    @Column(name = "hora_fim")
    // @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    private LocalTime horarioFinal;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id_equipamento", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Equipamento equipamento;

    @Transient
    private List<AgendaFuncionamento> listaDisponibilidade;
    
    ...
    
    }
```

Quando eu chamo o método insert pra gravar ele está gravando o conteudo da listaAgendaFuncionamento automaticamente na tabela sre_agenda_funcionamento e como ainda não tenho a chave do equipamento recebo o erro:

```html
ERROR: null value in column "id_equipamento" violates not-null constraint
  Detalhe: Failing row contains (16, null, 1, 01:31:00, 02:10:00).
```

Pelo que eu entendi ele está tentando gravar a lista primeiro. Fiz um repository pra ele gravar o conteudo da lista após gravar o equipamento, mas ele está tentando gravar a lista de maneira automática.

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver tirando o CascadeType.ALL, pois o CascadeType.PERSIST estava causando isso...

```html
@Entity
@Table(schema = "pesquisa", name = "sre_equipamento")
public class Equipamento implements Serializable {

...

@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE}, mappedBy = "equipamento")
private List<AgendaFuncionamento> listaAgendaFuncionamento = new ArrayList<>();

...

}
```